# Stop values from being updated each type page is refreshed

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have two links on my cart page. One is the 'continue shopping' one that leads to the product catalog and the other is the 'checkout' one that leads to the order details page. The problem is that when ever I refresh the order details page, my order_id gets incremented and a new order is stored in the tables which I don't want. I used header(..) to stop this but it also doesn't seem to work.

```
session_start(); 
if(!isset($_SESSION["customer"])) 
{
header("location: customer_login.php"); // will not execute if loggedin.
exit();
}

// Connect to the MYSQL database.
include "storescripts/connect_to_mysql.php";
// Checks to see that the URL variable is set and that it exists in the database.

// Will be used to output the order elements.
$cartOutput = "";
if(isset($_SESSION["cart_array"]) && !empty($_SESSION["cart_array"]))
{

$customer=$_SESSION["customer"];

// Get the customer id against the username of the customer.
$sql=mysql_query("select customer_id from customer c where user_name='$customer'");
$productCount = mysql_num_rows($sql); // count the output amount.
if($productCount > 0)
{
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql))
    {
        $customer_id=$row["customer_id"];
    }   
}
else
{
    echo "This user doesn't exist in our database.";    
    exit();
}

mysql_query("insert into orders(order_date,customer_id,payment_id)    
values(now(),'$customer_id',2)")or die(mysql_error());


// Get the order id of the customer in order to store information in order2product table.
$sql2=mysql_query("select order_id from orders where customer_id='$customer_id'") or  
die(mysql_error());
$productCount = mysql_num_rows($sql2); // count the output amount.
if($productCount > 0)
{
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql2))
    {
        $order_id=$row["order_id"];
    }   
}
else
{
    echo "The customer id which you specified doesn't have an order id against it.";    
    exit();
}
foreach($_SESSION["cart_array"] as $listitem) 
{
    $item_id=$listitem['item_id'];
    $quantity=$listitem['quantity'];
    mysql_query("insert into order2product(Product_id,Order_id,quantity) 
    values('$item_id','$order_id','$quantity')") or die(mysql_error()); 
}

 header ("location:order_page.php");
 exit();
} most outer if condition ends

else ...
```

Comment: Why don't you just empty the $_SESSION variables after writing into database OR add an id in the order table, read it in a $_SESSION variable and check the id before writing?

Comment: I agree seems to me you would want to empty the cart session data after you invoke the order since anything after that should be considered part of a new order.

Comment: @valicu2000 why do I need to empty the session variables after writing it into the db? Also how can I go about to track each session variable through an id?

Comment: You have a condition there: "if(isset($_SESSION["cart_array"]) && !empty($_SESSION["cart_array"]))" that triggers the write in the database ... If you empty the $_SESSION["cart_array"], there will be no further writing in the table (ok, I admit this isn't the best solution). The second possibility is that In the same condition you check also isset($_SESSION["order_id"]), after the table write you put last insert id into that variable and, perhaps, just do an update if it's set.

Comment: Wouldn't making the cart array empty make the page to display an empty order table after refreshing? Isn't there a way to make the page display the same order table with the same details after refreshing?

Answer (score 0):

Developing a shopping cart and using `mysql_*` functions? You're asking for so many issues. I'd suggest PDO.

Anyhow, why not bind the `order_id` to a session and tie it to the DB.. Check if the session exists. If it exists, check it against the DB. If it exists there as well, use it! If not, then you can generate a new ID. From there, when you see empty orders - you can assume they are then abandoned orders after the session timeout period. Of course, there are other elegant solutions to this, but this should get you started.

Comment: Same question..how do I bind/track a session variable through order_id?

Comment: Look up PHP sessions.